# Support both landscape and portrait view in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and can't figure out the best way to support a landscape and portrait view. What are my options?

The portrait view will have control positioned completely differently to landscape.

Answer (score 0):

If i don't miss something and you mean mobile views', just add a new `bool` var (something like isLandscape) at you ViewModel to control which `DataTemplate` will be used. You can control it with triggers or any other ways.

I guess you need more tags for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Windows Platform has an `AdaptiveTrigger` which lets you specify under which conditions a given `VisualState` will be set. Using style setters you can then change the layout of the page to fit your needs.

WPF doesn't have this functionality, but you can certainly mimic it very closely using `VisualStateManager` with `Storyboards` and the `SizeChanged` event.

To the root element of your window's content you can add a `VisualStateManager` with two groups:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Landscape"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Portrait">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames  
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="SomeProperty" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="SomeElement">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="SomeValue"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                ...
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
```

Now in the code-behind you can wire-up the `Window`'s `SizeChanged` event:

```
this.SizeChanged += (s,e) =>
{
    //some condition you want to use to distinguish landscape and portrait
    if ( Width < Height )
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Portrait", false);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Landscape", false);
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can do everything in code, again using `SizeChanged` event, but in this case you need to reset every property to its default at first, if you have multiple states:

```
this.SizeChanged += (s,e) =>
{
    //reset all changed properties to default value here
    ...
    //some condition you want to use to distinguish landscape and portrait
    if ( Width < Height )
    {
        //set properties for portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: So would I copy across the <Grid> and all its children to the <VisualState> node?

Comment: The layout would look similar to this - http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2009/12/29/no-more-magic-strings-with-visualstatemanager-gotostate.aspx.  You just add the VisualStateManager element to the root of the view - usually the main Grid.